# Wordpress AJAX Load More Orderby Meta_VALUE_NUM

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Helo,
I have multiple meta_key value pairs inside my custom posts. So to work around this what I did is that I ran a WP_QUERY initially which creates an array of posts ID which I then pass to load more to load those.

The array that I build using WP_Query is in the correct order. However when I use the IDs in post_in parameter it is not displaying them in the given order. I have also tried to give `orderby="meta_value_num"` parameter but it doesnt work either.

Here is WP_QUERY which is working perfectly

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 
                                array( 
                                      'post_type' => 'properties', 
                                      'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                        'meta_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'key' => 'listing_type',
                                                    'value'   => array(3,2),
                                                    'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
                                                ),
                                                array(
                                                    'key'     => 'payment_status',
                                                    'value'   => 'yes',

                                                        ),                                              
                                                array(
                                                    'key'     => 'expired',
                                                    'value'   => 'no',



 - ),

                        ),
                                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                                        'meta_key' => 'listing_type',
                                        'order' => 'DESC' 
                                      ));
```

Here is the shortcode:

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="properties" post__in="'.implode(',',$featured).'" posts_per_page="10" scroll="false" transition="fade" button_label="'.$l_more.'" button_loading_label="'.$l_more_2.'" container_type="ul" css_classes="items",orderby="meta_value_num" meta_key="listing_type"]
```

However it doesnt order posts as it should because $featured array has it in required order. Even if I remove order by and meta_key parameter it doesnt work.

Please Help
Ahmar

Comment: If you echo the $loop, what does the query say?

Comment: _“However it doesnt order posts as it should because $featured array has it in required order.”_ – that it “should” do that, is only your assumption. Selecting posts by id in itself does not guarantee any order.

Comment: @WouterNeuteboom query works perfectly as intended and returns ID in correct order. However its the ajax load more that is not ordering data correctly

Comment: @CBroe as you can see in shortcode the meta_key meta_value_num isnt doing it either

Comment: Well I’d try with a correct shortcode syntax first … what is the comma doing there?

Comment: @CBroe comma sepearated ID list is correct syntax for Ajax Load More Plugin. I guess you havent used the plugin thanks for the support anyway :)

Comment: I am not talking about your id list, but the comma you put between attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have an error in your shortcode.

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="properties" post__in="'.implode(',',$featured).'" posts_per_page="10" scroll="false" transition="fade" button_label="'.$l_more.'" button_loading_label="'.$l_more_2.'" container_type="ul" css_classes="items" orderby="meta_value_num" meta_key="listing_type"]
```

Second, you should `orderby="post__in"` to preserve the `post__in` ordering.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters